# What's the meaning of 'faithful colour pigments'?

Tags: meaning

> CERAMIC ART - NOT FOR FOOD USE - FAITHFUL COLOUR PIGMENTS MAY POISON
> FOOD.

I'm trying to translate something written on a plate in my native language but I cannot find a meaning of [faithful](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/faithful) that makes sense. From what I can
[see](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk02fqU-01_Nws38floHKPZnoK_MeJA%3A1615400723688&ei=Ew9JYLnMKYqwa-6xtZgB&q=%22faithful%20colour%20pigments%22&oq=%22faithful%20colour%20pigments%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6CwgAELADEAgQChAeOggIABAIEAcQHjoKCAAQCBAHEAoQHjoGCAAQCBAeUNhJWJ1VYPZVaAJwAHgAgAGBAYgB0QmSAQMzLjiYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6yAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwj5objSrKbvAhUK2BoKHe5YDRMQ4dUDCA0&uact=5) it's a collocation. Even so, I still can't come up with a proper definition of **faithful** in this sentence.

Comment: Faithful could mean authentic, true to the original. As such, the toxic dyes are not for food use, but decor. I'm thinking that Barn Red is faithful as an old, native, and probably cheap pigment, not for eating.

Comment: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/faithful)'s definition as adjective² applies: *True to the facts or the original.*

Comment: Based on what you said, it literally means "Authentic colour pigments may poison food" - I guess I just don't understand the purpose of the word in the sentence. Aren't just colours poisonous in general?

Comment: One of the search results in your link simply lacks punctuation. "FAITHFUL COLOUR PIGMENTS MAY POISON FOOD FOR DECORATIVE PURPOSES ONLY PLEASE NOTE, THE STAND IS NOT INCLUDED PLEASE SEE PHOTOS" should be "FAITHFUL COLOUR PIGMENTS. MAY POISON FOOD. FOR DECORATIVE PURPOSES ONLY. PLEASE NOTE, THE STAND IS NOT INCLUDED. PLEASE SEE PHOTOS."